# Возможно ли отключить конкретную проверку не для всего кода, а в конкретном месте в статическом анализаторе coverity?

Tags: c, статический-анализ

Есть проблема, coverity находит ошибку(потенциальный OoB) в томе месте кода, где семантически этой проблемы возникнуть не может, из за ругани статического анализатора не хочется вносить в это место дополнительную проверку в чистом проекте. Можно ли как то сказать coverity чтоб он не делал конкретно эту проверку в конретном месте в коде?

Comment: Можно, обычно такие анализаторы содержат в той или иной форме хинты, обычно внутри комментариев в соответствующем ЯП.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52148105/suppress-messages-in-coverity-using-attributes

Comment: https://community.synopsys.com/s/article/how-to-add-code-annotation-I-do-not-know-which-name-should-exist-with-coverity